# Opening file in VSCode Explorer using keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press Command+Shift+E (Mac) to set focus to the explorer in Visual Studio Code, I can navigate using the up and down keys to select a file, but I can't open the file in the editor.  I can press Enter to rename it, but I couldn't find a way to open the file using the keyboard.  Is there a way?

Comment: BTW, I know I can use Command+P, but if files are of the same name (e.g. index.ts), it's easier to be able to open using the explorer if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct shortcut to open a file is: CMD+down

Just for the record, this is the standard shortcut in any properly behaving OSX application, for example Finder.app (and it's the reason why Return/Enter renames a file)

Comment: Wow TIL, I always used Command+O in Finder so didn't know any better... thanks!

Comment: This answer helped me discover this gem of a link about Mac OS hotkeys: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201236. Specifically in this case: "Command–Down Arrow: Open the selected item.". And you thought that using Mac machines exclusively for > 10 years would have taught you something...